# Capture Net VS gathering/fishing

Tags: monster-hunter-world

The Capture Net can be used to catch fishes and bugs but there is still the original method of fishing/gathering(and now without the need for bugnets).

I would like to ask what is the difference between these methods? Does either affects the amount/quality?

So far I noticed that using a net causes fishes to flee from the fishing spot but for bugs it'd be a single gather either way. But what I am more curious about is that loot table from each method.

Comment: Is there even a loot table? Do the scout flies not tell you exactly what bug you're about to gather? Can you not see exactly what species of fish you're about to catch (at least in principle)?

Comment: If I know I wouldn't need to ask right? Last I shoot the net into a school of fish I caught two. I also got some misc from netting bugs so I just thought there might be a difference. The answer can be "no"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capture net is mainly used for *endemic life*. Bugs you can just go up and grab now, much quicker and reliable than deploying the net. As for fishing, sure you can use the net... but as you pointed out, this scares and scatters the fish whereas the fishing pole does not. The capture net also cannot use bait if you want to be going for specific kinds of fish.

Use the net if you want endemic life, your hands if you want bugs, the pole if you want to fish.

there is no loot table as you know what your getting when you see it (the scout flies tell you), and once you fish enough you'll just recognize what they are... no loot tables involved with gathering **life** (bonepiles and mining points and such still use a loot table)

Comment: So it is just possible to do so, no advantage doing so huh?